# wxPython GUI how to update frame with function result

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

I know this might be a simple question, but I am quite new to using python and wx. I am attempting to create a gui that reads an excel file and displays all rows on the screen that match user input search parameters and is triggered by a button click. I have been able to get the functions working and can get the results to print to my python terminal, but I am unsure of how to get them to appear in my gui frame. Does anybody know how to achieve this? I have stumbled across the grid class which may be useful but I have not had luck using this. Can anybody recommend a solution?
Many thanks

Comment: Hi welcome to SO!
Please add some code to your post otherwise people will not be able to help you. Please read the guidelines about asking questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Take a gander at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24292756/python-wxpython-importing-csv-file-onto-wxgrid-not-displaying-to-fit-on-frame

Comment: Use wxGlade to build your wxPython GUI. You will need to load the data that you read from excel in a grid (wx.Grid or wx.adv.Grid) There are many tutorials on this.
https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/04/04/wxpython-grid-tips-and-tricks/